# Creating a specific HTML layout

Tags: css, html

I need to create a specific layout in HTML.

Here is how

[image]

The colors are only for demo purpose. I want to create a editable area which starts inline with non editable text and continues in next line below the non editable text.

It is a requirement for creating a template in which user will add remove text directly.

Normal Divs and Sections did not help me here, can anyone give me some pointers?

I have tried following things,

- Setting a `Div` as `contenteditable` with a span in it having the non editable text
- I kept the Span out and tried to move it over Div which is bad solution and I had to use offset for text in div which breaks all the lines after the first.

This is a dynamically generated layout, so I can not readily keep the CSS dimensions ready before hand.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? or do you expect us to make it for you.

Comment: If you can make it, it would be great. I am not good with HTML specifically. I tried following
-Using top level div with contentEditable but that allows user to edit non editable text
-Tried using the Div along with a span, and float but it creates simple column based layout.

Comment: You might want to hire a front-end webdeveloper for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @merqri Can you please check out my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use images for the uneditable text, you can do this way by using an image as a background and work on it:

```css
body {font-family: 'Verdana'; font-size: 10pt;}
.editable {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/cAZvApm.png') -1px 1px no-repeat; text-indent: 8.5em; margin: 0 0 10px;}
```

```html
<div contenteditable class="editable">Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept. Learn more about incognito browsing.</div>

<div>Now try to edit the above text and check out!</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.querySelectorAll(".editable")[0]);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();        
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(document.querySelectorAll(".editable")[0]);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
  document.querySelectorAll(".editable")[0].focus();
</script>
```

#### Preview:

[image]

Comment: Hey, that is a start but it breaks when I press enter in the first line. I creates a column view. as the the caret remains just below the start of the first line.

Also, I am not really sure of creating images. The content is rendered dynamically. It is somewhat like a template engine, which creates a mixture of editable and non editable areas on the page.

Comment: @merqri This is how the browsers handle. Try pressing `Ctrl` + `Enter` instead of `Enter` alone. See if that works?

Comment: that worked like a charm. I am still not sure about using images. There would be lot of work involved considering the dynamic nature of data. Could there be a better way?

Comment: We need to think on that aspect as there's a lot of JavaScript to be used in this case, for dynamically generating the "effect". I won't say it is impossible, but I would say, it is possible with difficulty. I can help you with that! `:)`